# PowerShell: GetEventlog, time field is empty

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get selected objetcts from GetEventlog

```
$StartDay = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Get-EventLog -LogName application -After $StartDay | Select-Object Time, EntryType, Source, Message
```

but this is producing time field as empty column with no data. How to format time field to show data?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the property TIME not exist, you can use TIMEWRITTEN or TIMEGENERATED:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName application -After $StartDay | Select-Object Timegenerated, EntryType, Source, Message
```

Try this command to see exactly all properties:

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName application -After $StartDay )[0] | fl * #format-list
```

or

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName application -After $StartDay )[0] | gm #get-member
```